# How to properly make clean in kernel Makefile

Tags: linux, kbuild

I'm porting a driver to the 3.4 kernel, and when I do a make clean, it is not cleaning some .o files, so now I'm wondering what the proper way of doing this is.

I have the following Makefile (note: in a separate directory from the kernel):

```
obj-y += foo.o
foo-objs += foo1.o foo2.o
clean-files := foo3.o
```

When I run the make clean, it wipes out foo3.o, but leaves foo.o, foo1.o, and foo2.o.    I could put all of these into clean-files, but this seems redundant, and I would think that there would be some way to make the Makefile automatically wipe out all objects in obj-y directory.

Thanks,

John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regular expressions in makefiles, and write *.o instead of foo1.o, foo2.o, etc.

Common way is to have a 'clean' target, which looks like this:

```
clean:
    $(RM) .*.cmd *.o *.ko -r .tmp*
```

Comment: Two quick questions about this: 1) how does the clean target compare to the clean-files?  2) Also, what I had seemed to have worked in an older kernel (2.6.30).  Any ideas what might have changed?

Comment: It looks this variable is proceeded by kernel scripts: http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.6.7/scripts/Makefile.clean

Comment: It looks like the clean target is not being invoked in any of these Makefiles, which is the source of my problem.  The clean-files and clean-dirs are being wiped though...

Comment: So there are two solutions (both tested): first is to add *.[aos] to the clean-files macro.  The second is to modify the main linux makefile to add the third party directory to its rm -f command inside of clean.

Answer (score 2):

This is the way I used to `make clean` my driver code:

```
clean:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) M=$$PWD clean
```